# Getting the second greates number using conditionals

Tags: c

I'm learning a little of programming and my teacher asked us to make a program (in C) where we have to put the results of a car race, so we need to put:

1. Code of the car
2. Time of that car.

The car's code can be any number except the `999`. If the code is `999`, the program stops and shows:

1. First car in the race (the one with less time than the others).
2. Second car (the one with the second less time than the others).
3. Last car (the one with most time).

So, it looks very easy, but the problem is that we have to do it using just CONDITIONALS (`if/else`). NO arrays, NO vectors, just conditionals.

This is my code. I've made the first and the last but I can't find the way of getting the second car :(

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    main(){
        int carcode=0, cartime=0, i=0, first=0, firstcode=0, second=0, secode=0, last=0, lastcode=0, sum=0;
        float average=0.0;
        printf("Enter the code of the car: ");
        scanf("%i",&carcode);
        while(carcode != 999){
            printf("Enter the time of the car %d: ",carcode);
            scanf("%i",&cartime);
            i++;
            if(i==1){
                first=cartime;
                firstcode=carcode;
                second=cartime;
                secode=carcode;
                last=cartime;
                lastcode=carcode;
            }
            else if(i==2){
                if(cartime>first){
                second=cartime;
                secode=carcode;
                last=cartime;
                lastcode=carcode;
            }
            else{
                first=cartime;
                firstcode=carcode;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(cartime<=first){
                first=cartime; 
                firstcode=carcode;
            }
            if(cartime>first){
                if(cartime<=second){
                    second=cartime;
                    secode=carcode;
                }
            }
            if(cartime>last){
                last=cartime;
                lastcode=carcode;
            }
        }
        sum=sum+cartime;
        printf("\nEnter the code of the car: "); 
        scanf("%i",&carcode);
    }
    average= ((float)sum / (float)i);
    printf("The first car was the %d with %d minutes\n",firstcode,first);
    printf("The last car was the %d with %d minutes\n",lastcode,last);
    printf("The second car was the %d with %d minutes\n\n",secode,second);
    printf("The average time was %.2f",average);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `main()`--> `int main(void)`

Comment: @Fernando - please always format code properly (usually control/command f) before putting on here

Comment: http://ideone.com/y587LI : what exactly is not working?

Comment: @karma_geek I cant get the second car (the car with > time than the first but < than the others)

Comment: I think that there is a bit of mess in the initialization. Anyway, if you found a 'cartime<=first' ... maybe the previous 'first' should become the 'second'...

Comment: @karma_geek , Try entering three cars with times 7,5,3 and see the output.

Comment: Suggestion: average = ((float)sum / (float)i); => can simply do 'average = (float)sum / i'  or 'average = sum / (float)i'; i.e. as long as one of the operands is type cast, you will be ok. Don't need to type cast "sum" & "i".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind calculating the `second car` is that as soon as you change the `first car`, i.e., when you assign another car to the first car, the car which was currently holding the `first` position now moves to the `second`.

Suppose `car 1` is currently first. Now, another car, say `car 3` becomes first. Now what does `car 1` become? `Second`. So, update `car 1` as second.

Just before you assign something to `first car`, add the code to assign `first car` to `second` position. Eg:

```
 if(cartime<=first){
            second=first;
        secode=firstcode;
        first=cartime;
        firstcode=carcode;
    }
```

[Working code](http://ideone.com/ukPR4f)

Comment: Thanks bro! Luckily i realized this before you posted it. The first times i tried something like that but i put the code in the wrong way.